# Nasm - using multiplication on an address while dereferencing

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

When doing an operation like `mov [eax], ebx` you are able to use simple arithmetics on the value in the brackets. Like `mov [eax+10], ebx` or `mov [eax*8], ebx`.

When using addition you don't really have limitation what number to add. But when using multiplication you can only can use `1,2,4,8`, at least that's what I thought.

But operations like this: `mov [eax*3], ebx` or this: `mov [eax*9], ebx` seem to be valid. Other operations like: `mov [eax*6], ebx` or `mov [eax*7]` are invalid.

So, does anyone has an explanation for this?

Comment: Consult a manual. Technically `[eax*3]` is not valid, but your assembler may be able to turn it into `[eax*2+eax]` which is valid.